# Weird behaviour of drawableRight for Switch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I tried to do `android:drawableLeft` and `android:drawableRight` for `Switch`

`drawableLeft` is showing fine but `drawableRight` is showing behind the `track` of the Switch

how to make the track to display in center?

**My Code:**

```
<Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/moon"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/sun"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
         />
```

I am getting like this

switch Off

[image: switch Off]

Switch On

[image: Switch On]

Comment: Can you include the example that works?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto think that I used LinearLayout with same Switch without drawable right and I placed that drawable right image to one Imageview to achive that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it by adding 2 extra widgets like `Linearlayout` and `ImageView`

```
<LinearLayout
                style="@style/Wrap"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/Sw_am_pm_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/moon"
                    android:drawablePadding="6dp"
                    android:switchMinWidth="40dp"
                    android:textOff=""
                    android:textOn=""
                    android:thumb="@drawable/circle"
                    android:track="@drawable/bg" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/sun" />
            </LinearLayout>
```